# Reaction collector, display percentage (used for suggestions)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I've basically set up my suggestion bot, it's a very basis one but I'm looking to add a cool feature that will collect the positive and negative reactions and display a percentage. If the positive votes are more it would display 100%, if it's 1 positive and 1 negative it would display 50% and if it's negative it's 1 negative and nothing else it would display -100%. It's very simple but I'm struggling to understand how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, it would help if you could give some more context, such as a code example of what you have tried so far!

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know how to do that, I'm still fairly new to javascript. So far, I have my command which sends an embed to the #suggestions channel with the suggestion, and adds two reactions, positive and negative. I'm using `client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.embeds.length === 1 && message.embeds[0].title === 'New Suggestion') {
    message.react(':agree:722855964847636552')
    message.react(':disagree:722855999161237574')
  }
})`

Answer (score 1):

For handle reaction you can use method `createReactionCollector`, but the 1 one problem is: method not triggered on reaction remove. So you need use some interval to check message reaction.

`time: 120000` - its time to await reaction of millisecond, change it to whats you need.
If bot go restart hadling reactions will stop...

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith('test')) {
        let suggestion = message.content.substring(0, 4) //test length
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({
            dynamic:true,
            format: "png"
        }))
        embed.setTitle('Suggestion')
        embed.setColor('GOLD')
        embed.setDescription(suggestion)
        embed.setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(embed).then(msg => {
            msg.react('').then(() => msg.react(''))
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return [``, ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name)
            };
            let check = setInterval(handleReaction, 5000, message, msg, suggestion)
            const collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter, {
                time: 120000,
            });
            collector.on('collect', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {
                handleReaction(message, msg, suggestion)
            });
            collector.on('end', (reaction, reactionCollector) => {;
                clearInterval(check)
            });
        })
    }
})

function handleReaction (message, msg, suggestion) {
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    let positiveReaction = msg.reactions.cache.get('')
    let negativeReaction = msg.reactions.cache.get('')
    let negativeCount = negativeReaction ? negativeReaction.count : 0
    let positiveCount = positiveReaction ? positiveReaction.count : 0
    embed.setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({
        dynamic:true,
        format: "png"
    }))
    embed.setTitle('Suggestion')
    embed.setColor('GOLD')
    embed.setDescription(suggestion)
    embed.addField('Votes', ` - ${(positiveCount / (positiveCount + negativeCount) * 100).toFixed(2)}%\n - ${(negativeCount / (positiveCount + negativeCount) * 100).toFixed(2)}%`)
    embed.setTimestamp()
    msg.edit(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Really Now If This Is What You Were Looking For Directly But Here Is My Old Code From An Old Bot I Had

```
    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    if (!args.length) {
            return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any text! <:angry:713422454688710717>`);
        }
    const sentMessage = await client.channels.get(< CHANNEL ID HERE >).send({embed: {
    color: 700000,
    author: {
      name: client.user.username,
    },
    title: "Suggestion",
    description: sayMessage,
    footer: {
      timestamp: new Date(),
      icon_url: client.user.avatarURL,
      text: "Suggestion"
    }
  }});
    message.react('');
    sentMessage.react('').then(sentMessage.react(''))
    message.channel.send("To vote for a suggestion, join my server. It should just be ..server!")
```

What It Does Is It Takes The Users Message  And Puts It In An Embed And Reacts With Thumbs Up And Thumbs Down In The Channel Of Your Choice
But It May Need To Be Updated A Bit If Your Using V.12

Comment: Basically what I want is another Field in my embed which will always get updated when a reaction is added/removed, like this https://imgur.com/nk5Xnka